# akka scala compilation error arrow

Tags: scala, akka

When I try to compile a version of akka from cloned repository I get following error:

```
FSMActorSpec.scala:82: not found: value →
[error]       case Locked → Open ⇒ transitionLatch.open
[error]                   ^
```

There are also other errors all related to this "arrow" thing.

I confirmed that when I try to compile a simple file where I use "→" it works just fine.

Akka seems to set scalacOptions -encoding="UTF-8".

I also tried to manually replace all occurrences of "→" with "->" but scala formatting changes it back again ... and this is not a solution anyway.

Do you have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Can you maybe provide more info on the environment and how you are trying to build this? I tried this for you, followed the steps [in the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/dev/building-akka.html) and successfully compiled Akka master on Windows, Java 1.8.0_45.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I am using:
Arch linux, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)

Comment: It could be related to https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/19746